# Reusable model AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am in a scenario where I need to be able to reuse a model. Basically, a user selects a dynamic amount of items on one view, and then they need to input various data for each of the items they selected in the following view.

For example, on view #1, I choose, "A, D, G".

Then on view #2, I have to fill out the following for A, D, G:

A: Name, Color, Age

D: Name, Color, Age

G: Name, Color, Age

Originally, I had it set up like this but realized that it wasn't very reusable:

```
angular.module('itemApp')
  .directive('itemInfo', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/directives/item-info.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      controllerAs: 'item',
      scope: {
       myItems: '='
      }, 
      controller: function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.myItems = $scope.myItems;
        vm.hideNextItem = false;
        vm.hidePrevItem = false;
        vm.currentItem = vm.myItems[0];
        vm.itemStep = '1';
        vm.itemInfo = {
          name: '',
          color: '',
          age: ''
        }
        ...
      }
    };
  });
```

Then I would use ng-repeat in the view to retrieve the information for the first item, push it into an array in the service, reset the model, use a function to select the next item, change the item step, and then repeat. Is there some way I can set up the itemInfo model in a service, somehow create a copy of it for each item, and store the info for each item in an array in the service? That way I would have all three item info available in the service and I wouldn't have to worry about resetting models etc. in a directive. Ultimately, I want to take the array of all three items and make a call to a webservice once this step is completed which would be much easier if all of the data was in one place.

Comment: A directive should not know anything about an `Itemservice`. You should use bindings to feed the data to your directive.

Comment: of course you can implement the way you want.. your question is not clear as to why it is not possible, where u r stuck.. a plunker would really help

Comment: add `bindToController: true` to your directive, instead of injecting your `$scope` to your controller.